# How to install Ghostscript with the proTeXt download?

Tags: installing, miktex, ghostscript, protext

I've installed MikTex using the [proTeXt](http://www.tug.org/protext/)  Installation. Since the Ghostscript is already included in this big `proTeXt` file, how should I install it?

Could I install from the package manager of the MiKTeX or should I install the Ghostscript independently by just running the `.exe` file contained in the `proTeXt` ?

To clarify, I installed MiKTeX using `protext setup.exe` file. But Ghostscript is not installed for whatever reason I don't know during the installation. Now I want to install the Ghostscript so is there a way to add the installation of Ghostscript using the package manager of the MiKTeX or should I just install `gs` independently.

Comment: Did you not have a similar version of [short pdf document:page 5](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/MiscDocs/l2h/protext-install-en.pdf) inside protext installation that guides the installation automatically. `Should I install the Ghostscript independently by just running the .exe file contained in the proTeXt:` **Answer: Yes incase you failed using short pdf route** Although I don't use proTeXt now so not much clear idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[proTeXt](http://www.tug.org/protext/) 2013 installation has a similar latest version of [short pdf document:page 5](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/MiscDocs/l2h/protext-install-en.pdf) that guides the MiKTeX,TeXStudio(replaced with TeXniccenter),Ghostscript and GSview installation.

"Should I install the Ghostscript independently by just running the .exe file contained in the proTeXt"

**Answer**: Yes incase you failed using short pdf route Although I don't use proTeXt now so not much clear idea.

Not recommended for a very new user but incase you wish to [install Ghostscript separately](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/) via website. If you find any issues please [report](http://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/protext) them with proper errors and specifications of computer although there are [no known bugs](http://www.tug.org/protext/bugs.html) reported.